# Python cannot convert string to float sometimes

Tags: python, string, floating-point

I have the following two codes:

1.

```
f=open("file.csv","r")
data=f.read()
f.close()
for line in data.split("\n"):
    for d in line.split(","):
        print(float(d))
```

2.

```
f=open("file.csv","r")
data=f.read()
f.close()
for line in data.split("\n"):
    for d in line.split(","):
        float(d)
```

The first code runs fine, but the second gives the error:

ValueError: could not convert string to float:

What is wrong with the second code?

This is the first two lines of the file:

```
0,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,0
0,49.805,69.3666,78.4413,83.2828,86.1354,87.9128,89.0309,89.6942,90.0045,90.0045
```

Comment: both codes are identical.Only differs by the print statement. I suppose that one of your fields is just empty.

Comment: Don't use the snippet tool for Python. It only works for HTML/CSS/JavaScript.

Comment: I included part of my sample file. I do not think that my fields are empty.

Comment: Open this csv file in notepad++ and check for blank line at the end - its almost certain the case, because normally when there is something to convert it would look like this: `ValueError: could not conver string to float: something`

Comment: How do I mark my question as answered?

Comment: I tried this *without* a blank line at the end, and still got a problem: the trailing '\n' on the final line still generates a blank item.

Comment: @programjames: you wait the require time span (15 minutes) and then select an answer.  If you like Shan's explanation, ask him to post it as an answer.  If you like something else (including not mine), post an answer of your own and accept *that*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your only "empty" field is the end-of-file after the final newline.  I used the following code to diagnose.  However, I was not able to make this code pass without error; even your first version throws the exception.

```
f=open("file.csv","r")
data=f.read()
f.close()
for line in data.split("\n"):
    for d in line.split(","):
        print('|' + d + '|')
        print(float(d))

    print("----------------------")
```

This results in

```
|0|
0.0
|100|
100.0
|100|
100.0
|100|
100.0
|100|
100.0
|100|
100.0
|100|
100.0
|100|
100.0
|100|
100.0
|100|
100.0
|100|
100.0
|100|
100.0
|100|
100.0
|100|
100.0
|100|
100.0
|100|
100.0
|100|
100.0
|100|
100.0
|100|
100.0
|0|
0.0
----------------------
|0|
0.0
|49.805|
49.805
|69.3666|
69.3666
|78.4413|
78.4413
|83.2828|
83.2828
|86.1354|
86.1354
|87.9128|
87.9128
|89.0309|
89.0309
|89.6942|
89.6942
|90.0045|
90.0045
|90.0045|
90.0045
----------------------
||
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(float(d))
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

**Solution**

Use the `with` statement and get your input one line at a time:

```
with open("file.csv","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        for d in line.split(","):
            print(float(d))
```

I think this gives you the needed functionality.